# mload gives different results for result uint8 and bytes1

Tags: remix

In remix.ethereum.org, converting from bytes to bytes1 works but from bytes to uint8 does not. Since both bytes1 and uint8 are represented as binary the assembly should be able to convert between both. Why does bytes to uint8 fail?

This returns 0, should return 255

```
function c() returns(uint8) {

uint8 input;
bytes memory b = hex"FF";

assembly {
     input := mload(add(b, 32))
}
return input;
}
```

This works, returns 0xFF

```
function c() returns(bytes1) {

bytes1 input;
bytes memory b = hex"FF";

assembly {
     input := mload(add(b, 32))
}
return input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due how casting from bytes32 works in solidity

```
function foo() public {
    bytes32 a = 0xff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000BB;
    uint8 b = uint8(a);
    bytes1 c = bytes1(a);
    require(b == 0xBB);
    require(c == 0xFF);
    log3("hello!", bytes32(a), bytes32(b), bytes32(c));
}
```

Casting to `uintXXX` will use less significant bytes, and casting to `bytesXXX` will use the more significant bytes.